# How do I obtain version information from the calling application

Tags: c#, version, assemblies

I have a web application written in C# and running as a dll under IIS.

I also have some common code compiled to a separate assembly (dll).  This common code contains a function that returns version information (as below).  How can I modify this code so it returns the version information of the web app dll and NOT the common code dll as present ?

```
...
    private static Assembly _assy;

    private static void CheckAssemblyInfoLoaded()
    {
      if (_assy == null)
      {
        _assy = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
      }
    }

    public static string Version
    {
      get {
        CheckAssemblyInfoLoaded();
        Version v = _assy.GetName().Version;
        return v.ToString();
      }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the assembly reference using the `Assembly.GetAssembly(Type type)` method, where you pass in the type of any object defined in that assembly, such as `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass));`

Comment: Thanks Jay - I'll give it a spin.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd drop the static and combine the method into one.

```
    public string GetVersion()
    {
        Assembly assy = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        Version v = assy.GetName().Version;
        return v.ToString();
    }
```

static in this scenerio could produce some unwanted results.  I also changed the property to a method; a personal design choice.

Your getting the wrong assembly because the properties get method bounces off another method in the same assembly thereby changing the caller.

Comment: Thanks - but your suggestion does not address the issue of which assembly is referenced to obtain the information from (Jay's does).
Also, my code as shown is part of a  static class that also returns other version/assembly information such as copyright, description, company name etc.